# Bash use something other than '~' to represent home directory?

Tags: bash, shell, sh, zsh

Is it possible with bash (or maybe even zsh) to use a character other than the tilde ("~") do designate one's home directory?  For example, "cd ~" takes you to your home directory.  Hitting the shift key with my right pinky and then ~ key with my left pinky simultaneously has always seemed very awkward to me, particularly since it's a keystroke combination that's used so much.  Is there another way to do this?  I don't want to have to type $HOME all the time either.  Ideally, I'd like to be able to use something more natural like shift+$ or shift+% instead of shift+~.  Can this be done?  By the way, I'm not looking for a shortcut such as "cd" to get back to my home directory.  I want to make it easier to get to directories beneath my home directory.

Comment: I always use the thumb of my left hand to hit the `shift` key, and my middle finger to hit the `~`.

Comment: BTW, configuration for the readline library (used by bash) can be used to map whatever keypress to whatever character you want.

Comment: ...that said, I question whether this is on-topic here: StackOverflow's scope is *software development*; configuring your shell, as opposed to writing scripts for it, is a better fit for [unix.se] or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: @CrisLuengo That sounds even worse!  ;-)

Comment: @Charles Duffy: since bash is also a programming language, the question is, strictly speaking: how could one define an embedded domain specific language in bash, which allows to access certain directories in a more convenient way? It's a one-symbol language, but still...

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, there are already too many questions not about programming. That's the truth. I believe there's no solution for it.

Comment: @EmilyE., certainly true, but that's not a reason to give up trying, any more than we'd want to give up trying to avoid spam, trolling, or other unwanted content were the site plagued with same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several proposals that cannot work:

- "shift+~" is just a symbol, not some weird metakey-combo!
- "shift+%" gives a '%', which is already reserved for job
  control
- "shift+$" gives a '$', which is already reserved for variables and spawning child processes as in '$(cat blah)'

Some ideas that might work:

- Instead of using $HOME, define $H in ~/.bashrc. That's only 2 characters, and $ is much less complicated to type
- If it's your computer, you could create a symlink '/h' that points to your home directory, so that you could type `/h/foo/bar` instead of `~/foo/bar`.

Comment: I like the idea of defining $H but it appears that you can no longer complete a path using the Tab key if you use this approach.

Comment: That's the advantage of using a symlink... In principle, one could even redefine `cd` in such a way that whenever you change into a directory, a link called `H` to /home/you is generated, so that you can access your home directory in the same way you can access `.` and `..`. However, if you aren't careful, this could quickly lead to unwanted links all over the place, and those would make various build tools go mad (e.g. maven crashes if there are cycles in the source directory structure).

Comment: @William do you mean a recent change has stopped completion expanding the variable, or this arrangement prevents it?

Comment: @Guy My bad, command line completion still works.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I like your approach the best.  I've defined "$h" in my .bashrc file and use that environment variable in place of ~.

Comment: @William: Even a "nontrivial combination of the last two proposals!", I would say ;) Just in case you are tempted to try it out: I've checked whether some slightly more obscure symbols might work as well, but e.g. neither $_ nor $: worked. The ':' is not alphanumeric and not underscore. The "$_" is treated specially as some argument to the previous command.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `cd` without arguments to go to the `HOME` directory.

See [man bash](https://ss64.com/bash/cd.html)

Comment: This does not generalize well to other commands or paths relative to the home directory? What's with e.g. "vim ~/.bashrc"?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin `cd`, then `vim .bashrc` ;)

Comment: @Benjamin W. : "cat fileInCurrentDirectoryBuriedVeryDeepInFileSystem >> ~/.bashrc"?

Answer (score 3):

You can remap backtick `` ` `` to tilde `~` in Bash. With a US keyboard layout, this saves you a Shift:

```
bind '"`": "~"'
```

This only affects the shell prompt, and has the additional benefit of reminding you to always use `$(..)` over deprecated `` `..` `` for command substitution.